# Is it possible to run migrations from TFS without adding the new ReflectedWorkItemId field to all work item templates?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-migration-tools

I would like to run some test migrations that don't change the source in any way.

1. Is this possible?
2. Alternatively, could an external file be used for the sync state instead of relying on editing the work item templates in the TFS source?

Reference link: https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/server-configuration.html

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't change the source. The reflected work item ID field is only needed in the target.

Comment: Why the downvote??

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT, until I'm able to try it (I can't for a while now) -- still planning I can't confirm it works.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to run migrations from TFS without adding the new ReflectedWorkItemId field to all work item templates?

The answer is that the `ReflectedWorkItemId` field is not necessarily needed.

As we know, the `ReflectedWorkItemId` field is used to provide sync as well as migration it is important that the tools knows which items have already been migrated.

The `ReflectedWorkItemId` field needs to be added to the **Target Project Work Items**. And If you add the field to the **source** (yes it needs to be the same refname), and set `UpdateSoureReflectedId` to true then you can also filter the source.

So, if we do not need to filter the source, we could not add the new `ReflectedWorkItemId` field to the source.

You could check the MrHinsh`s replied:

> Guys, The field is not required in either case, however... if you
> don't have the field then the system cant be re-run as it will re-copy
> all completed work items. If you add the field to the target then it
> will only copy those items it cant find. If you add the field to the
> source (yes it needs to be the same refname), and set
> UpdateSoureReflectedId to true then you can also filter the source,
> using a query and limit what you load.
>
> The former prevents duplicates, and the latter allows you to filter
> the data load...

You could check [this thread](https://gitmemory.com/issue/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/353/541965276) for some more details.

Comment: We added a check for ReflectedWorkItemId in the Target as it is required there. Not required in Source.